# WP8: can't bind string

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

i'm new to WP development. i'm trying to use strings saved in AppResources.resx
as the default comments generated by visual studio says, i have to replace the hard-coded text between quotes in value Text of the TextBlock with `Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"`

this don't show any error, but if i try to change the value of the string in the file, it don't change in the preview of the page.

also I've tried to create a new string but if I try to display the value, nothing happens.

I don't declared anything about supported languages, only created a new project and tried do do this.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: You need to build the solution before the designer views update.

Comment: Please try Source = {DynamicResource LocalizedStrings} instead of {StaticResource LocalizedStrings}

Comment: @jlahd building the solution works.

Comment: @vimalCK replace Static with Dynamic result in a error. should i import something?

Comment: just build your project..it is working for me..change the string My application to hello my app or something else..then just build..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build and run the app, and the strings will appear in the app and designer afterwards